# Unable run mongo shell in Ubuntu 16.04 after restart

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am unable to access mongo shell in Ubuntu 16.04, but am able to run

> sudo mongod

and its working , but when i try to run

> mongo or sudo mongo

the following error raises

> MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
>
> connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 2017-07-26T14:33:50.413+0000
>   W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking
>   socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
>   2017-07-26T14:33:50.414+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't
>   connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13 @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed

Comment: How about `sudo service mongod start`.

Comment: @Burdy  I checked with   
**sudo service mongod start**   
but the when i checked the status  using 
 **sudo service mongod status**  
I got this
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-07-26 14:43:16 UTC; 6s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2086 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 2086 (code=exited, status=100)

Answer (score 0):

Print the last line of  cat **/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log**  and the content of **/etc/mongod.conf**.

Ensure that in **/etc/mongod.conf** the dbPath exists, the port is correctly bind to 27017, host is 127.0.0.1

In addition try to remove the mongod socket file **/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock**

Comment: When i try to cat /etc/mongod.conf i got this 
**# mongod.conf
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
#processManagement:
#security:
#operationProfiling:
#replication:
#sharding: `**

Comment: I reinstalled mongodb , but now when i try to start the servive 
`sudo systemctl start mongodb.service`
am getting message like
`Failed to start mongodb.service: Unknown unit: mongodb.service`

Comment: just "sudo systemctl start mongod"

Comment: run the command
`sudo systemctl start mongod`
Got it thanks :-)